# Cannot expand or collapse v-list veutify

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am having issues with Vuetify `v-list` and `v-list-group`, I am trying to make a list and it does not expand nor collapse, I have tried to modify it myself and tried to copy and paste (from here https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#sub-group, this also adding necessary props and models) but nothing. Not sure what I am doing wrong, I am not sure if it's the `v-slot` not working. I am using vite with vue 3 and vuetify 3.

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" width="300">
    <v-list v-model:opened="open">
      <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-home" title="Home"></v-list-item>

      <v-list-group value="Users">
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle" title="Users"></v-list-item>
        </template>

        <v-list-group value="Admin">
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item title="Admin"></v-list-item>
          </template>

          <v-list-item v-for="([title], i) in admins" :key="i" :title="title" :value="title"></v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>

        <v-list-group value="Actions">
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item title="Actions"></v-list-item>
          </template>
          <v-list-item v-for="([title], i) in cruds" :key="i" :value="title" :title="title"></v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>


<script lang="ts" setup>
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'

const open = ['Users'];
const admins = [
  ['Management', 'mdi-account-multiple-outline'],
  ['Settings', 'mdi-cog-outline'],
];
const cruds = [
  ['Create', 'mdi-plus-outline'],
  ['Read', 'mdi-file-outline'],
  ['Update', 'mdi-update'],
  ['Delete', 'mdi-delete'],
];

const links = ['Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi'];
const buttonLinks = ['Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings', 'Hi', 'Contacts', 'Settings'];
const mini = true;
const items = [
  { title: 'Hello', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard' },
  { title: 'About', icon: 'mdi-forum' },
];
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using vue 3 I assume you're using vuetify 3?  That version is still in beta, meaning bugs and missing features from vuetify 2 are to be expected.  You're also consulting the wrong docs, use [this link](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#sub-group) instead.  You can try following the examples there but there is NO guarantee that components will work as expected until it's out of beta (currently estimated to be end of year).

Comment: yes I am, and thank you for the suggestion, although I tried this with veutify2 and this still doesn't work or can't find a way to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, and once again hopefully the Veutify team will post more appropriate examples of their library

```html
    <template>
      <v-card class="mx-auto" width="300">
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-home" title="Home"></v-list-item>
    
          <v-list-group value="Users">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-list-item v-bind="props" prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle" title="Users"></v-list-item>
            </template>
    
            <v-list-group value="Admin">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Admin"></v-list-item>
              </template>
    
              <v-list-item v-for="(title, i) in admins" :key="i" :title="title" :value="title">
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-group>
    
            <v-list-group value="Actions">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Actions"></v-list-item>
              </template>
    
              <v-list-item v-for="(title, i) in cruds" :key="i" :value="title" :title="title">
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-group>
          </v-list-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </template>
```

Notice how I removed the `<v-list v-model:opened="open">` from `<v-list>` that was the main problem, even if you don't pass in props and create a temporary array this will work and your list will collapse and expand